# When throwing a die $3$ times, what is the probability of the product of the three results being a multiple of $9$?

Tags: probability

When throwing a die $3$ times, find the probability of the product of the three results being a multiple of $9$.

I tried drawing a table for the possible outcomes of the first TWO dice. Then I tried considering the cases for each when the third die is rolled - as you can imagine not very efficient. Perhaps I could use $x+y+z = 9k$ as a divisibility test, where $k$ is an integer. I'm pretty sure this would involve stars and bars, but I'm not sure how to implement it in this case. Would I have to solve for $k$?

I also worked out the boundaries but I'm not sure if that will help either: $9≤x+y+z≤216$.

Do I need to use stars and bars for this question?

Comment: The product is a multiple of $9$ if and only if at least two of the rolls are a multiple of $3$. Does that help?

Comment: Take two of the rolls as 3 or 6, then multiply all cases of the third roll.

Comment: You can't use stars and bars as assignments using stars and bars aren't equiprobable

Comment: Where did you get $x + y + z$? Nothing is added in this problem. The numbers on each roll of the die are **multiplied**.

Comment: @DavidK oh yes sorry, I was using the divisibility rule that if the sum of the digits is divisible by $9$, then the entire number is divisible by $9$. Hence $ ++=9$ where $k$ is integral

Comment: So, what are $x,y,z$? Are they the digits of the product of the three rolls? If they are, doesn't that just make it vital to know the joint probability distribution of those three digits? It seems this makes the problem harder, not easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not agree with this solution.

I obtained the result $\frac{7}{27}$

In fact, the probability to have a product divisible by 9 means that, among 3 die's rolls, at least 2 must be #$3$ or #$6$, thus

$$\binom{3}{2}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^2\cdot\frac{2}{3}+\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^3=\frac{7}{27}$$

Comment: Thanks, this makes it look so easy. For some reason divisibility by $9$ meaning two threes or two sixes didn't come across to me

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it quickly by counting the cases when the product is not divisible by $9$.

- Number of all throws: $\color{blue}{6^3}$
- Number of throws containing neither $3$ nor $6$: $\color{blue}{4^3}$
- Number of throws containing exactly one $3$: $\color{blue}{3\cdot 4^2}$
- Number of throws containing exactly one $6$: $\color{blue}{3\cdot 4^2}$

Hence, the probability $P$ of a throw with a product divisible by $9$ is

$$P = \color{blue}{\frac{6^3-4^3 -3\cdot 4^2 - 3\cdot 4^2}{6^3}}= \frac{7}{27}$$

Answer (score 0):

I agree with tommik's solution. Here is a simulation in R to verify.

```
# Number of simulations
nsims <- 1e7

roll <- function() sample(1:6, size=1)

# Generate products
products <- purrr::map_dbl(1:nsims, ~roll()*roll()*roll())

# Get proportion divisible by 9
sum((products %% 9) == 0) / nsims
```

```
0.2592488
```

which is about $\frac{7}{27} = 0.259259259...$